# How to compute the sensitivity(recall) with different false positives per image

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I am focus on the Object Detection. But I am confused about how to compute the sensitivity with specific false positives.

For example, as show in the below picture, how can I plot it? Is there any github repo for that? Thank you very much!
[image]

Comment: Actually, It mean how to compute it...

Comment: Please do not use the comments section for this kind of unsolicited clarifications - edit & update your post instead.

Comment: OK, Thanks, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scikit-learn's [recall_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html). You will need to call it once per image and feed it the predicted and true labels of that image only.

Comment: Thanks, In the recall score function, it need the length of y_true and y_pred is same. However in detection, I think it maybe not same?

Comment: Yes that's true. You're better off calculation mAP to measure the performance of your object detector. Read this [blog post](https://medium.com/@timothycarlen/understanding-the-map-evaluation-metric-for-object-detection-a07fe6962cf3) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260430/average-precision-in-object-detection) for more info.